# Can this NodeJS cluster master crash?

Tags: node.js, express, restart, forever, node-cluster

We have been using `forever` to launch our Express app, which uses [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to spawn workers that do all the work. That means the master is only running this code:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {

    // ...
    // ... check arguments and do some initial prep 
    // ...

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    // Listen for dying workers
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
        if (!worker.suicide) {
            // Replace the dead worker if not a startup error like port in use.
            console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died. Replacing it.');
            cluster.fork();
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

Given that the master isn't really doing anything, is there any need to "protect" it with `forever`, `supervisor`, etc? Is there any situation in which the master could crash and there would be value in automatically restarting it?

Comment: You use protections like forever to protect you from things you don't know might happen.

Comment: Like what? What's an example of something that could cause a node process to crash, but which wouldn't stop it restarting?

Comment: Well, the last software guy I met that thought there was a piece of code that absolutely nothing could go wrong with because he couldn't think of anything off the top of his head ... was wrong.  There are always things that can go wrong that you aren't aware of.  IMO, its foolish not to take simple precautions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is no need to monitor the master process in your cluster, because you won't be able to handle `SIGKILL`.

Refer to [`PM2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) [implementation as below](https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/), which is `master` actually.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');  
var http    = require('http');  
var os      = require('os');

var numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {  
  // Master:
  // Let's fork as many workers as you have CPU cores

  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  // Worker:
  // Let's spawn a HTTP server
  // (Workers can share any TCP connection.
  //  In this case its a HTTP server)

  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world");
  }).listen(8080);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  How does this show that the master process could never have a problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 He was probably referring to the fact that you can handle the error within NodeJS itself, but with a separate process, which makes sense since no system in itself is invulnerable. It's just a matter of how many error handlers you have (monitoring processes) to increase the redundancy factor.